# Iscroll Javascript Ajax Request at pull end?

Tags: javascript, ajax, javascript-framework, iscroll, pull-request

i got nearly the same as in this example here: [Tutorial for iScroll](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/introduction-to-iscroll/)

The Thing i want is to do a Ajax Request at the End of the Scrolling, like Facebook does for example. Can i do this with this iscroll framework?

If i can do this with it. How? :)

Comment: I suggest that you reply in comments or by editing your question if the answer does not work. If it does though, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When constructing your iScroll, you should give a function as the `onBeforeScrollEnd(that, event)` or `onScrollEnd(that)` option (I don't now which one is the best).

Inside that function, you check whether `that.y == that.maxScrollY` in which case you are at the end of your vertical scrolling.